# POST a response from API by AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, post

Im making a Login whit facebook.
using the javascript sdk im geting the response (i guess is JSON), and i want to send this response to a php file to check if the user is in the database or not.

so heres what i got so far.
this is the function i call when the user is loged into facebook.

```
 function testing(){
    FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
    response = JSON.stringify(response);
    //call another function, sending the data recived
    ajaxlog(response);
    });

    }
```

and here is the ajaxlog function

```
function ajaxlog(facedatos){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "facebook-ajax-login.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: facedatos,
      success: function(response){
        //the php brings the conect response true or false
        if(response.conect==true){
          $("#exist").html(response.data);
        }else{

        }
      },
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#exist").html("<img class='img-responsive ajax-l' style='width:40px;padding-top:10px;margin-right:10px;' src='images/ajax-loader.gif' />")
      }
    });//<!--ajax-->
```

im doing alerts and the facebook data comes with no problem. i think the issue is how i send the data by post, im not reciving the data in the php

Comment: What does FireBug show as the post data. Does that look right?

Comment: Is the PHP file location correctly entered?

Comment: all seems ok:
`
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-ar,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection keep-alive
Content-Length 475
`
may be its the php not reving well the data... here is the testing php

`$objeto = json_decode($_POST["facedatos"]);

$data = array(
    "conect"=>true,
    "conectado"=>$objeto
    );
echo json_encode($data);
die;`

Comment: yes the php is in same directory

Comment: i just checked if the response was empty or was  null and its null...

Comment: may be the ajax sending the data wrong??

`data: facedatos,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the issue by myself,
the problem is that i was sending the post request whitout a name.
in the ajax function changed

```
data: facedatos,
```

for

```
data:{
  face: facedatos
}
```

and in the php recived the data as `$_POST["face"];`